# How can I compile c++ opengl code using Atom?

Tags: c++, mingw, static-linking

So I've installed **gpp-compiler** extension for **Atom**, I've put glut.h into my `MinGW\include\GL` directory as well as I've put `libglu32.a` file into my `MinGW\lib` directory and also I didn't forget to put `glut32.dll`,`glu32.dll` into `C:\Windows\System32` and I've also put `glu32.dll` into `C:\Windows\SysWOW64`.

This is the compiler configuration I've got:
[settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eo8Pv.png)

And that's the compiling error I'm getting:

`b:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lglut32
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status`

Looking forward to your answers :)

Comment: Problem solved, the issue was that my libglut32.a was called libglut32.win.a, renaming it solved the problem. https://i.imgur.com/ugk8Goq.png

Comment: OK, sop ignore my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The linker is not able to find the library **glut32.a**.

You need to add the folder via

```
-L<folder containing glut32.a>
```

to your C++ compiler command line options, where you already declared the libs which shall be linked to your application.